# How to view this sql select query with a map with Apache Camel?

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel

I'm currently building a Spring Boot application which runs multiple select queries. From my understanding the output of a select query is in the form of a map. I want to make the output viewable from my console, but it's not working. Not sure if something is going wrong in my route or that my Map is not defined correctly. The last run it gave me the following exception : cannot be cast to class java.util.HashMap (org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap is in unnamed module of loader

This is the route:

```
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:Timer?period=60000")
                //.setHeader("CamelSqlQuery", constant(selectBridgeQuery))
                .routeId("test route")
                .to("sql:select * from basetimestamps?dataSource=#dataSource")
                .bean(databaseStorage, "monitor")
                .to("log:result")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Output: ${body}");
    }
}
```

And this is the map:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseStorage {

    public void monitor(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        List<HashMap> out = (ArrayList<HashMap>) exchange.getIn().getBody();

        try{
            for(HashMap outContent:out){
                String message = outContent.get("output_obj").toString();

                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```